# The requested URL was not found on the server error while trying to implement sell function with sqlite and flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am working on a function that has to access a portfolio of stocks, sell the requested number of stocks if owned at the current price and update the database.
I am able the select the stock and the number of shares but when I click the sell button, I am having the following message:

> The requested URL was not found on the server. GET /sell%20method=?symbol=amzn&shares=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 - .

Please have a look at my code:

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():

    """Sell shares of stock"""
    #Access the current user
    user_id= session["user_id"]

    if request.method =="POST":
        if not request.form.get("symbol") or not request.form.get("shares"):
            return apology("Enter a valid symbol or number of shares")

        #Define data
        symbol=request.form.get("symbol")
        shares=request.form.get("shares")
        stock=lookup(symbol)
        price=stock.get("price")
        total_cost=int(shares)*stock["price"]
        name=stock.get("name")
        transaction_type="sale"
        if stock is None:
            return apology("Enter a valid symbol")

        #Access existing data in DB

        rows= db.execute("SELECT symbol, shares FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=user_id)

        #Validate if the current user owns the shares they are trying to sell
        for row in rows:
            if row["symbol"]==symbol:
                if shares > row["shares"]:
                    return apology("Enter a valid number of shares")

        users=db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", user_id=user_id)
        new_cash=user[0]["cash"]+total_cost

        #Add transaction to the db
        #Update DB cash of the user
        db.execute ("UPDATE users SET cash=:new_cash WHERE id=:id", new_cash=new_cash, id=user_id)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO stocks (user_id, symbol, name, shares, price, total_cost, transaction_type) VALUES(:user_id, :symbol, :name, :shares, :price, :total_cost, :transaction_type)", user_id=user_id, name=name, symbol=symbol, shares= -1*shares, price=price, total_cost=total_cost, transaction_type=transaction_type)

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        share_symbols=[]
        symbs = db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY symbol", 
        user_id=user_id)
        for symb in symbs:
            share_symbols.append(symb)
        return render_template("sell.html", share_symbols=share_symbols)
enter code here
```

INDEX  and BUY functions

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():

    user_id=session["user_id"]
    user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", user_id=user_id,)
    cash = user[0]["cash"]

    rows= db.execute("SELECT symbol, name, sum(shares) as shares, price, sum(price*shares) as total_cost, sum(total_cost) as total_cost_sum FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=user_id)
    total_cost_sum=0

    for row in rows:

        name=row["name"]
        symbol=row["symbol"]
        shares=int(row["shares"])
        quoted_stock=lookup(symbol)
        price=float(quoted_stock["price"])
        total_cost=float(shares*price)
        total_cost_sum+=total_cost


    grand_total=total_cost_sum+cash
    return render_template("index.html", cash=cash, rows=rows, grand_total=grand_total)


@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""


    if request.method =="POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        stock = lookup(symbol)
        shares= int(request.form.get("shares"))
        price = stock.get("price")
        total_cost= shares*stock["price"]
        name= stock.get("name")
        transaction_type="purchase"
        #Validations
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Choose a stock to buy!")

        if stock is None:
            return apology ("Enter a valid symbol")
        if not shares or shares < 1:
            return apology("Enter a valid number of shares to buy!")
        #validating that the current user is the one who bought the shares and who sees the portfolio
        user_id = session["user_id"]

        user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", user_id=user_id)

        balance = user[0]["cash"]-total_cost

        if total_cost > balance:
            return apology("Not enough funds")
        else:
            db.execute ("UPDATE users SET cash=:balance WHERE id=:id", balance=balance, id=user_id)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO stocks(user_id, symbol, name, shares, price, total_cost, transaction_type ) VALUES(:user_id, :symbol, :name, :shares, :price, :total_cost, :transaction_type)", user_id=user_id, name=name, symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=price, total_cost=total_cost, transaction_type=transaction_type)

        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

SELL HTML

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Sell
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
     <form action="/sell method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="symbol">
            <option disabled selected value=""> Symbol </option>
            {% for share_symbol in share_symbols %}
                <option value="{{share_symbol.symbol}}"> {{share_symbol.symbol}} </option>

            {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="text">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share what your route for '/' looks like? And also what your sell.html file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `"` from `action` attribute on `<form>` tag.

Change `<form action="/sell method="post">` to `<form action="/sell" method="post">`